# Is it preferable to normalize the data between [0-1] before running PCA

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I'm interested to know if it is recommended to scale a matrix from some integer range (e.g 0-255) to [0.0-1.0] before running a PCA. Does it affect the floating point error?

Comment: If rounding error is of concern to you, and your data is not of an unwieldy size, have you considered using exact arithmetic for your calculations?

Comment: the ieee min unsigned float is 2^−150. You can safely multiply your numbers by 2^-8 :)

Comment: @user603 Your reasoning is good but your [facts are off a little](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point): for floats the minimum (non-denormalized) absolute value is $2^{-126}$; for doubles it is $2^{-1022}$.

Comment: @whuber: thanks for the link and for correcting me:)